# Messaging app with channels

Tags: web-apps, chat, hosted

[Telegram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(service)) has been recently blocked in Iran and we might have to use a different messaging app. A useful feature of Telegram is channels. Is there a messenger providing the same or a similar feature?

#### Notes

- Telegram is a hosted web app, like [WhatsApp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp).
- It has different clients for different platforms.
- [Wikipedia about the Channels feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(service)#Channels):

  > Channels can be created for broadcasting messages to an unlimited number of subscribers. Channels can be publicly available with an alias and a permanent URL so anyone can join. Users who join a channel can see the entire message history. Each message has its own view counter, showing how many users have seen this message. Users can join and leave channels at any time. Furthermore, users can mute a channel, meaning that the user will still receive messages, but won't be notified.

  More info: [Channels FAQ](https://telegram.org/faq_channels)

Comment: Discord, Slack and Microsoft Teams have this.